# Set up equation for addition markdown in a store price

Tags: problem-solving, percentages

I am having trouble setting up an equation for a specific type of percent problem. Here is an example to help clarify.

```
Keith wants to mark all of the original prices in his store down to half off. The prices are already marked down by 20%. What additional percent should be discounted?
```

An explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An item that used to list at $\$100$ now sells for $\$80$ (that's the $20\%$ discounted price). How much should you discount that $\$80$ to make the price $\$50$?

Comment: 37.5%  ... not that hard.